# Best Practice - Lots of migrations in a huge dev team

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We struggle a little and need some fresh ideas how to handle the migration-stuff.
We are acute developing new features and extensions for a huge website with a lot of new migrations (altering tables and ofc neu tables).

Every time if its getting close to merge into master or deploy the app we struggle a lot of the current scheme.

for example: 
current version: 100

i create some migrations, 101, 102, 103, 104.
in another new branch i create 101, 102

my coworker is doing the same.

In total we are having 12 new migrations and its a mess to pull some other branches, running the migrations due its conflicting.

What is the best practice so handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to update your Ruby on Rails version to something more recent than a few years old. Then you will have timestamped migrations. They were definitely present in Rails 3 (current version is 4), and I'm not completely sure, but I think they were even in some older versions of Rails 2.

> Migrations are stored as files in the db/migrate directory, one for each migration class. The name of the file is of the form YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_create_products.rb, that is to say a UTC timestamp identifying the migration followed by an underscore followed by the name of the migration. The name of the migration class (CamelCased version) should match the latter part of the file name. For example 20080906120000_create_products.rb should define class CreateProducts and 20080906120001_add_details_to_products.rb should define AddDetailsToProducts. Rails uses this timestamp to determine which migration should be run and in what order, so if you're copying a migration from another application or generate a file yourself, be aware of its position in the order.
>
> http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-migration

**UPD**. As was clarified in comments, the problem is the need to merge `schema.rb` file, not the migration files. Just add `db/schema.rb` to `.gitignore`. If you don't use `rake db:schema:load` and friends, it's okay to do so.

Comment: timestamped is since rails 1 i guess. but that wont change the behavior since the schema is always the highest timestamp-version. that means if i merge a feature from today and then from yesterday it still stuck. or am i wrong?

Comment: Ah well, now I understand you, you are having trouble merging `schema.rb` file, right? Well, if you don't do things like `rake db:schema:load` (and you probably shouldn't use that with the development approach you use), just add it to .gitignore.